# Unsure how to resolve "Cannot resolve constructor" error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting an error on a particular fragment (which is one of three on a tabbed activity).  The error is:

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(layout.OneWayFragmen,int,java.lang.string[])'
```

I am trying to include and autocomplete field on one fragment of a tabbed activity.  The java class in question is below:

```
package layout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import com.example.alibasmaci.maral.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class OneWayFragment extends Fragment {


    public OneWayFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static OneWayFragment newInstance() {
        OneWayFragment fragment = new OneWayFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_way, container, false);

        String[] cities =

                {"Ottawa - Carp CYRP",
                "Toronto - Billy Bishop CYYZ",
                "Montreal - St. Hubert CYHU"
                };

        AutoCompleteTextView actvDeparture;
        actvDeparture = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.actvDeparture);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,cities);
        actvDeparture.setThreshold(1);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

The error I am referring to is a result of this line:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,cities);
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayAdapter's constructor takes the `Context` as the first parameter, and you're passing `this` from `Fragment`, which essentially means you're passing a `Fragment` in this line:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,cities);
```

What you should do is pass the activity that it's attached to like:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,cities);
```

An even better way to do it is to declare it as a field and initialize it in `onAttach` method like:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,cities);
}
```

**EDIT**: You're also missing this line:

```
actvDeparture.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I noticed I was missing
actvDeparture.setAdapter(adapter);  So i edited the code in the question

Comment: Well, I don't know what it might be then. Maybe you should create your own adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter<String>` or something like that. Since my post helped you solve the problem, you should consider accepting the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter accepts Context for the first parameter and you can pass the context by calling getActivity().

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,cities);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that there is no such constructor like:

```
 ArrayAdapter(Fragment, int, T[])
```

Change the reference `this` for  `getActivity()` so you can get the context propely,

after that it will match the constructor

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) is a *generic* class. You haven't specified the generic type argument, so you're using it *raw*, which is **bad**. It should be `ArrayAdapter<String>`.

It has 6 constructors:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

You method call has this signature:

```
ArrayAdapter(layout.OneWayFragmen,int,java.lang.string[])
```

That *might* fit the 3rd constructor, but only if `layout.OneWayFragmen` is a `Context`. Is it?